# Sql Server 2014 Express

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm new to this kind of stuff because I am just a college student so I hope you wont get annoyed how dumb I am.

So first I have created a sql server with a default instance name, I created that with only windows authentication, I've been using that for a while and it has a database with few tables that I am using for my project, a while ago I want to try creating a server with a sql authentication. So I created one. and set the password as 'admin' then I tried connecting to the previous windows auth only server that I created. Then I tried clicking the database that I am using and I cant seem to access it and it has the word '(Single User)', so I wondered if I can access it by connecting to the newly created server and it seems that db only exists in the previously created server and cant access it to my newly created one. now my problem is why cant I access the database in my old sql server by connecting to the old sql server? it should still be possible right?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. Are you saying, you have installed two SQL server engines on same machine? And SQL server versions are same too?